# Incorrect time is displayed on the site

Tags: 7, datetime

I just noticed that incorrect time is being displayed in my website. The time is 6 minutes lagging from the correct time.

For example:

- The current time in Japan/Tokyo is 4:07 PM Saturday, July 22, 2017
  (GMT+9)
- The current time as per website is  4:01 PM Saturday, July
  22, 2017 (GMT+9)

Any guess? Why is it happening? how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server time? Run the date command on your server if you have cli access or check it in your cPanel.